# Creating custom methods

Tags: ruby, arrays, class, methods

What is best practice / syntax for trying to extract internal methods within a class?

```
class Foo

  def initialize
  end

  def get_value
    array = (API CALL TO GET ARRAY)
    array.array_lookup("Bar")
  end

  def array_lookup(query)
    self.each do |hash|
      if hash[:key] == query
         p hash[:value]
      end
    end
  end

end

foo = Foo.new
foo.get_value #=> : undefined method `array_lookup' for #<Array:0x007fd3a49a2ca0 (NoMethodError)
```

The error message is telling me that my array object doesn't know how to respond to my method which makes sense in that I have an array that doesn't have this method, though I'm wondering how to fix this and similar uses. Do I overwrite the array class?  Do I change my self.syntax?

Comment: Remember it's `class`, lower-case, and not `Class`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this? You turn your custom object into a subclass of Array so you get the array methods like `#each`. Actually, come to think of it, a better implementation might include mixing in the `Enumerable` module into your custom class (thinking composition over inheritance).

```
class Foo < Array
  # More robust to change in application if you allow passing
  # the query into this method. Just a suggestion.
  def get_value(query)
    request_data
    lookup(query)
  end

protected

  def request_data
    # API call to get data, assume this is array with contents
    data = []
    # Set contents of this object to contents of returned array
    replace(data)
  end

  def lookup(query)
    each do |hash|
      if hash[:key] == query
        puts hash[:value]
      end
    end
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.get_value("BAR")
```

Answer (score 1):

array_lookup is Foo's method. So inside Foo class, you can call it by

```
array_lookup("Bar")
```

(without `array.`)

Comment: This method is relevant to the array it is being called on as it iterates through the array; therefore are you suggesting I make array_lookup take an array and query, like such?  def array_lookup(array, query) array.each do... end  How can I just call this method on my array?

Comment: If you're calling a method on a Foo instance, it **must be** a Foo instance, not just some random array. Otherwise, as you observe, you must pass it in as an argument. It's not like JavaScript where you can rebind arbitrarily.